# React routing based on id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, nested-routes

I work with `react-router` v6. I want to create a new route based on an id. On my homepage `"example.com"` I have a selection of articles. I want to create a detail view for each article `"example.com/{id}"`.  My approach looks like this:

App.tsx

```
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Routes,
  Route,
} from "react-router-dom";
import ProjectWrapper from "./components/ProjectWrapper";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import PageError from "./pages/PageError";

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} >
          <Route path=":id" element={<ProjectWrapper />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<PageError />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

ProjectWrapper.tsx

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { ProjectList } from "../pages/algorithms/ProjectList";
import PageError from "../pages/PageError";

function ProjectWrapper() {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const project = ProjectList.find((project) => project.id.toLowerCase() === id?.toLowerCase());
 
  if (project === undefined) return (<PageError />);
 
  return (
    <div>
      {project!.shortDescription} 
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProjectWrapper;
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: what worked/didn't work? do you see any errors?

Comment: No errors can be seen in the terminal.
On 'www.example.com' the Home component can be seen
as well as at 'www.example.com/{something}. At 'www.example.com/{something}/{something}. It shows my Error component.

It doesn't matter if the id is valid or not only the home component is rendered

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the given routing code:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} >
    <Route path=":id" element={<ProjectWrapper />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<PageError />} />
</Routes>
```

`Home` is what is called a [Layout Route](https://reactrouter.com/en/v6.3.0/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes). Layout routes render some common logic and UI, ***and*** an `Outlet` component for ***nested*** `Route`s to render their content when matched.

Example:

```
import { ..., Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
  ...

  return (
    <>
      ...

      <Outlet /> // <-- nested routes render content here
    </>
  );
};
```

If you ***don't*** want the `Home` component to render along with children routes then place it on its own route.

Examples:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  <Route path="/:id" element={<ProjectWrapper />} />
  <Route path="*" element={<PageError />} />
</Routes>
```

or

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/">
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path=":id" element={<ProjectWrapper />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="*" element={<PageError />} />
</Routes>
```